# Tcl/Tk: Applying theme (awdark) to an application

Tags: themes, tcl, tk-toolkit

I would like to apply the awdark theme to refresh an old apllication. Unable to apply themes using tcl awthemes https://sourceforge.net/projects/tcl-awthemes/, or even the default built in Themes like classic, vista, xpnative.

In the working code below the the "awdark" theme is being applied and I can confirm this by asking `ttk::style theme use`. But I dont see any changes on the styling of the GUI

```
lappend auto_path "C:/Root/tcl_tk/33_Dummy_Analyzer_2022/awthemes-10.4.0"
package require awdark
#
ttk::style theme use awdark
#
label .l_inst -text "Instructions: fill in the below fields and click 'Go'"  
label .l_year -text "Enter the digits for year, eg 22: "  
grid config .l_inst  -column 0 -row 0 -columnspan 2 -sticky "w"
grid config .l_year  -column 0 -row 1  -sticky "e"
#
set autofill1 22   
entry .e_year -bg white -textvariable autofill1 -validate key \
-vcmd {expr {[string is digit %P] && [string length %P]<=2}} -width 20 
grid config .e_year  -column 1 -row 1  -sticky "e"
#
button .b_go -relief raised -overrelief ridge -borderwidth 5 -text "GO"
button .b_quit -relief raised -overrelief ridge   -borderwidth 5 \
-text "Cancel and Close"
grid config .b_go -column 0 -row 8  -sticky "snew" -pady 10
grid config .b_quit -column 1 -row 8 -sticky "snew" -pady 10
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use [ttk::widget](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_widget.html) to apply a theme, for this replace :

- *label* by [ttk::label](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_label.html)
- *entry* by [ttk::entry](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_entry.html)
- *button* by [ttk::button](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/ttk_button.html)

*Note* : Be careful not all properties apply for `ttk::widget`

Comment: Yes, have to go ttk all the way. That would mean I would have to rethink some sections, short keywords like `-vcmd`, `bg`, `fg` will throw errors. The entire background can be changed using `tk_setPalette background #33393b` etc.